# Formik checkbox won't re-render

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik library and have a simple form with one checkbox that I would like to submit on change:

```
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ toggle: false }}
      validateOnChange={false}
      validateOnBlur={false}
      onSubmit={(values, { validateForm }) => {
        validateForm().then(_errors => {
          console.log(values);
        });
      }}
    >
      {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
        <div>          
          <form onChange={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Toggle
              <input
                name="toggle"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={values.toggle}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </label>
          </form>
        </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

For some reason, it looks like the input is not being re-render after every click, only after every second click. As a result checkbox is not being update - you have to click twice for it to change (onChange event only fires every second time)

I can force it to re-render by adding `key` but it's a hack.

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-checkbox-issue-ew65e

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to submit the form at every change.

Idealy you should debounce this behaviour (using lodash maybe ?) :

```
import _ from 'lodash'

<form onChange={_.debounce(handleSubmit, 300)}>
```

Alternatively, if you don't use lodash, you can make the call to handleSubmit asynchronous by wrapping it in a setTimeout like this :

```
<form onChange={() => setTimeout(handleSubmit, 0)}>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I think this won't help - `form` is in inside Formiks render props function so this debounce effectively will just delay the execution of submitting. You can see here that it will submit the form as many times as you click the checkbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-checkbox-issue-78nkb

I can move debounce to `onSubmit` handler but then I get an ugly delay when clicking checkbox - not something you would do

Comment: I am not sure I get your problem then... You were trying to submit the same way before but the debouncing solves your update problem. If you don't want to submit each time the checkbox changes than you shouldn't give `handleSubmit` to `onChange` in `form`

Comment: I wanted each onChange to fire onSubmit - my idea was to debounce in handleSubmit function so I won't really submit on every change. 
If I understand your suggestion I should use debounce on forms onChange to solve the update problem but then I need another one in the handleSubmit function to prevent submit on every change?
This is confusing

Comment: Also please note that this is only a checkbox problem - if I add text input, this works fine

Comment: Well with an input you also call handleSubmit on every key stroke if you don't debounce. I figured out the problem with the debounce. The function reference is lost each time the component rerenders, it is why it didn't work that well. I am now keeping the reference using React.useRef(). You can see it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-checkbox-issue-e3gpj

Comment: But the input doesn't need double key press to work just like checkbox does.
Thanks a lot for your help - your solution works although it doesn't exaplain the behaviour